# How do I specify that an XML::Simple data point is a node and not an attribute?

Tags: perl, xml-serialization, xml-simple

I'm trying to build XML that looks like this using XML::Simple:

```
<response>
    <device>
        <interface>
            <mh>0x123abc</mh>
            <portname>Gi1/1</portname>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <mh>0x123abc</mh>
            <portname>Gi1/1</portname>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <mh>0x123abc</mh>
            <portname>Gi1/1</portname>
        </interface>
    </device>
</response>
```

I'm finding XML::Simple very difficult to behave like I want, so I tried feeding it it's own medicine:

```
$req = <<EOF;
<response>
    <device>
        <interface>
            <mh>0x123abc</mh>
            <portname>Gi1/1</portname>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <mh>0x123abc</mh>
            <portname>Gi1/1</portname>
        </interface>
        <interface>
            <mh>0x123abc</mh>
            <portname>Gi1/1</portname>
        </interface>
    </device>
</response>
EOF
print Dumper(XML::Simple::XMLin($req));
```

yields:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'device' => {
                      'interface' => [
                                     {
                                       'portname' => 'Gi1/1',
                                       'mh' => '0x123abc'
                                     },
                                     {
                                       'portname' => 'Gi1/1',
                                       'mh' => '0x123abc'
                                     },
                                     {
                                       'mh' => '0x123abc',
                                       'portname' => 'Gi1/1'
                                     }
                                   ]
                    }
        };
```

If I feed that back into XML::Simple and print it:

```
my $xml = XML::Simple::XMLout($VAR1, RootName => "response");
print $xml;
```

I get this, which doesn't match what I sent it in the first place:

```
<response>
  <device>
    <interface mh="0x123abc" portname="Gi1/1" />
    <interface mh="0x123abc" portname="Gi1/1" />
    <interface mh="0x123abc" portname="Gi1/1" />
  </device>
</response>
```

How do I tell XML::Simple to treat a node as a node and not an attribute?

Comment: Re "I'm finding XML::Simple very difficult to behave like I want", XML::Simple is hard to use for reading XML. It's hopeless for generating XML.

Comment: `ForceArray => 1` when reading might do the trick

Comment: Clearly, it's inappropriately named.

Comment: xml purists would say the two forms are supposed to be interchangeable.

Comment: @ysth, What??? Schemas clearly distinguish between attributes and elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is [`XML::Simple NoAttr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#NoAttr-1-in-out---handy)

> #### NoAttr => 1 # in+out - handy
>
> When used with XMLout(), the generated XML will contain no attributes. All hash key/values will be represented as nested elements instead.
>
> When used with XMLin(), any attributes in the XML will be ignored.

However, from the documentation for [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE)

> #### STATUS OF THIS MODULE
>
> The ***use of this module in new code is discouraged***. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.
>
> The major problems with this module are the large number of options and the arbitrary ways in which these options interact - often with unexpected results.
>
> Patches with bug fixes and documentation fixes are welcome, but new features are unlikely to be added.

Therefore, I would strongly recommend that you use either `XML::LibXML` or `XML::Twig` because of the very problems that you're facing right now.

Trust us.  This will likely be the first of many, even if this solution does work.

Comment: NoAttr works - I'm working in a highly controlled environment, but I'll see about switching.  Thank you for the warning.

Comment: note that there's nothing *wrong* with XML::Simple - except that some of its defaults are not what many expect

Comment: Not wrong, just awful for so many reason (bad defaults being the smallest of problems).

Comment: @ysth, there's not much wrong with the *implementation* of XML::Simple. The problem is the entire *premise* behind it: that you can losslessly (or with acceptable data loss) map between arbitrary hash/array structures and an XML infoset.